# Findall - certain range

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.6, findall

I have expression correct find desire variables but I wish to only prints like second result and then third results and so on. Is there like better way doing this? Maybe adding to SQL database and recall it from it?

The final goal to display these results within a windows and sources is RSS feed with first 2 result not desired so I hoping like `range` command where I can choose to select third results like `[2]`.

```
str1 = open("source/news.xml")
file_contents = str1.read()
title=file_contents.find('<item><title>(.+?)<\/title>')

j = 2
while i < 10:
    i = i+1
    trending = Label(the_window2, text=title[j+1], font=('Arial', 12))
    trending.grid(column = 1, row = i, padx = 2, columnspan=4)
```

Or

using xml.etree

```
xmltext = ET.parse('source/old_news.xml')
root = xmltext.getroot()
for title in root:
    print(title.attrib)
```

SQL Method: 
I can't seem to get SQL loop working as error: `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"`

```
connection = connect(database = 'source/old_news.db')
news = connection.cursor()

str1 = open("source/old_news.xml")
file_contents = str1.read()



for item in file_contents['items']:
    title = item.title
    link = item.link
    description = item.description
    print (title)
    print (link)
    print (description)

    connection.execute("INSERT INTO ini (title, link, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (title, link, description))
    print ('Succesfull!')
```

Comment: Given that you are reading RSS, which is XML, you should use python's built in XML support such as https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: @scotty3785 Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated OP and is this correct way or doing this? It seem to print out empty '{}'.